# C# JsonConvertDeserialization returning null values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to understand why I am getting null values for the following:

Json:

```
{
  "IdentityService": {
    "IdentityTtlInSeconds": "90",
    "LookupDelayInMillis": "3000"
  }
}
```

Class:

```
public class IdentityService
{
    public string IdentityTtlInSeconds { get; set; }

    public string LookupDelayInMillis { get; set; }
}
```

Called with :

```
  _identityService = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IdentityService>(itemAsString);
```

The class is instantiated but the values for IdentityTtlInSeconds and LookupDelayInMillis are null. I cannot see why they should be

Comment: Deserialize to dynamic instead of your class. see what it deserializes to and make sure your class is like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one more class - an object which has one property called `IdentityService`:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public IdentityService IdentityService { get; set; }
}
```

You need this class because JSON that you have has one property called `IdentityService`, and this object has two properties, called `IdentityTtlInSeconds` and `LookupDelayInMillis`. If you are using a default serializer your classes need to reflect the structure that you have in your JSON string.

And now you can use it to deserialize your string:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(itemAsString);
_identityService = rootObject.IdentityService;
```

Comment: Or remove IdentityService from the json so that the data contains only the properties and you can deserialize directly to an IdentityService.